# Python sqlite3 multiple pattern search

Tags: python, select, sqlite

I'd like to search for multiple pattern with one query, for example :

```
 select * from rates where host IN ('host1', 'host2') and epoch<1376492112 and epoch>137649200;
```

I don't know how to make it possible with python, keeping in mind that I can have one or more hosts to search.

It would look like this :

```
t = (','.join(hosts), fromdate, todate,)
db = 'db.sqlite'
conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT host, ops FROM rates WHERE host IN (?) AND epoch<? AND epoch>?', t)
rawresults = c.fetchall()
conn.close()
```

But as you can guess this won't work if I have several hosts (there will be a shifting, and my second host will be used as the epoch variable in the sql request)

Any idea ?